# MDIPArentForm: I'am working with a project in c# , i have a page which is the Menueform this form i worked by MDIPArent form

Tags: c#, vb.net

**

The result from the above tittle that i write is I wont to ask how to increase the default size of the MDIParentform , becouse the size of the form not enough to display all the data that i would to write.

**

### Thank you.

Comment: The maximum size of the MDI parent form would be the same as screen width, but that will not give you a wider menubar than the width of the screen.

Comment: yes, i know that but the question is there is any solution to increase the default size (width and height) for the form ?

Comment: What ever size you set in code or designer will become the default size... 'Form1.Width = 800'